How are catch clauses registered in dart for Future error handling
May be a very naive question but I'm trying to wrap my head around error handling in dart with async await but I'm unable to reason the following case
void main() async {
  print(await func1());
}

Future<bool> func1() {
  try {
    return func2();
  } catch (e) {
    print('got here');
    return Future.value(false);
  }
}

Future<bool> func2() async{
  final result = await func3();
  return result;
}

Future<bool> func3(){
  throw new Exception('Hello');
}


The above example throws an exception however if I wrap the top level main function in try catch, the exception gets caught
void main() async {
  try {
    print(await func1());
  } catch (e) {
    print('Top Level Catch');
  }
}

Future<bool> func1() {
  try {
    return func2();
  } catch (e) {
    print('got here');
    return Future.value(false);
  }
}

Future<bool> func2() async {
  final result = await func3();
  return result;
}

Future<bool> func3() {
  throw new Exception('Hello');
}


Why is it the case that the catch block in func1 does not get triggered to catch the exception
Tried going through the dart docs but could not find a good resource for such a case

func1 does not await the Future returned by calling func2.  It just returns the Future.  However, there is a desire to change this behavior; see https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/870

That issue wouldn't apply to func1 since it's not an async function.
If func1 had been async, then the return should have awaited the future, but it's currently implemented in a way that makes that await happen outside of the function, not inside the try/catch.
